# Exception while connecting to MongoDB using spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, exception

I am trying to connect to a `MongoDB` instance from my testcases. I am getting the below error...

`Mongo` process is up and running. Any thoughts on the error reason?

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: can't call something : localhost:12346/test; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : localhost:12346/test
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1644)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1507)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:489)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:484)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$SingleEntityExecution.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:313)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy69.findById(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.ServiceImpl.save(ServiceImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy71.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.SearchTestCase.setUp(SearchTestCase.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1197)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1122)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : localhost:12346/test
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:227)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:626)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1684)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1503)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.bson.io.PoolOutputBuffer.pipe(PoolOutputBuffer.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.pipe(OutMessage.java:111)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:119)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:218)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your `mongod` process running on port 123456?

The default port for `mongod` is **27017**. I'd suggest altering your connection string to run on this port instead of **123465**.

Comment: I'm using at 127.0.1.1:27017, but the problem also exists

Comment: I was running an integration test where port was configured 12345, and whenever I was running the junit tests with maven, it was throwing DataAccessResourceFailureException. It did not throw any exception if I was running the tests from eclipse. Anyway, after changing the port to default one, as suggested in this answer, my maven build was a success. so +1.